# How can I p2v a windows gaming machine to KVM inplace?

Tags: windows, kvm, gpu-passthrough

I have a windows gaming machine which I'd like to convert to linux (specifically fedora), yet retain it's functionality as a gaming platform.

I was wondering if p2v the windows to a KVM image with GPU passthrough would achieve this, but I have a few concerns:

1. If the GPU is bound to the guest OS, how can I view the host? I don't have any experience with this kind of setup, never tried to passthrough a GPU, so I'm not sure how this would work. Perhaps IOMMU and the GPU gets shared with the host?
2. I've searched for windows p2v tools, only found for MS virt formats. I know I can convert MS virt to KVM friendly format but if I can do this in a single step I'd prefer that.
3. Will this have native performance?
4. How can this be done inplace? I would assume a bootable USB stick, but how can I convert the single HDD, without additional storage elsewhere? The disk is about 30% full currently.
5. I'm wondering if it won't be simpler to just fresh install a windows vm, but I have several dozen games already installed and reinstalling them will take time (mostly steam and gog games, so installation time is the only concern).

The question, then, is:
How can this be done?
and
Should I do it?
Will I achieve the benefit of a linux workstation with windows gaming in the weekends?

Comment: With 30% free space - what speaks against a simple dual booting system? Or a separate hard drive for that matter.

Comment: `libvirt` supports using a disk as a storage pool; each VM is installed into a partition. With some cleverness it *may* be possible to create the VM in-place. The key to making this work is that you need some space prior to your first partition in order to wrap all of the Windows partitions inside of a partition. You'd have nested partitions. Please add the output of `fdisk -l /dev/sd*`.

Comment: @Fiximan Dualboot means an either/or system, which is less than ideal. I'd rather be able to step out of a game as needed, read an email, check on compile progress or do anything I don't want to in windows and return to the game when I feel like it. Dual boot would be worse than current linux in vbox.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa I'd rather create a disk image file, if possible. I think it will be easier to manage in the long run (taking snapshots, cloning etc.)